# mongo1:27017: exception: aggregation result exceeds maximum document size (16MB)

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I'm trying to run a mongo query in my laravel app but receiving the error listed in the title of this post. I think I need to set `useCursor` to `true` but am having trouble getting it to work. Here's my code:

```
    $email_duplicates = User::raw(function ($collection) {
        return $collection->aggregate(
            [
                [
                    '$group' => [
                        '_id' => [
                            'email' => '$email',
                        ],
                        'uniqueIds' => [
                            '$addToSet' => '$_id',
                        ],
                        'count' => [
                            '$sum' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    '$match' => [
                        'count' => [
                            '$gt' => 1,
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            [
                'allowDiskUse' => true,
            ],
            [
                'useCursor' => true,
            ]
        );
    });
```

anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!